# Equidistant points across Bezier curves

Tags: graphics, interpolation, bezier, curve

Currently, I'm attempting to make multiple beziers have equidistant points.  I'm currently using cubic interpolation to find the points, but because the way beziers work some areas are more dense than others and proving gross for texture mapping because of the variable distance.  **Is there a way to find points on a bezier by distance rather than by percentage?  Furthermore, is it possible to extend this to multiple connected curves?**

Comment: See also http://math.stackexchange.com/a/61796/589.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

distance between P_0 and P_3 (in cubic form), yes, but I think you knew that, is straight forward.

Distance on a curve is just arc length:

[fig 1 http://www.codecogs.com/eq.latex?%5Cint_%7Bt_0%7D%5E%7Bt_1%7D%20%7B%20|P'(t)|%20dt](http://www.codecogs.com/eq.latex?%5Cint_%7Bt_0%7D%5E%7Bt_1%7D%20%7B%20|P'(t)|%20dt)

where:

[fig 2 http://www.codecogs.com/eq.latex?P%27(t)%20=%20[%7Bx%27,y%27,z%27%7D]%20=%20[%7B%5Cfrac%7Bdx(t)%7D%7Bdt%7D,%5Cfrac%7Bdy(t)%7D%7Bdt%7D,%5Cfrac%7Bdz(t)%7D%7Bdt%7D%7D]](http://www.codecogs.com/eq.latex?P%27(t)%20=%20[%7Bx%27,y%27,z%27%7D]%20=%20[%7B%5Cfrac%7Bdx(t)%7D%7Bdt%7D,%5Cfrac%7Bdy(t)%7D%7Bdt%7D,%5Cfrac%7Bdz(t)%7D%7Bdt%7D%7D])

[(see the rest)](http://steve.hollasch.net/cgindex/curves/cbezarclen.html)

Probably, you'd have t_0 = 0, t_1 = 1.0, and dz(t) = 0 (2d plane).

Comment: This is how you find the arc length given the parameter, but finding equidistant points requires the inverse of this function. Getting from one to the other is not trivial. @Christian Romo: how did you do it? I mean, you can just use binary search, but that would be horribly slow (for what I'm trying to do, anyway).

Answer (score 9):

This is called "arc length" parameterization.  I wrote a paper about this several years ago:

http://www.saccade.com/writing/graphics/RE-PARAM.PDF

The idea is to pre-compute a "parameterization" curve, and evaluate the curve through that.

Comment: Haven't read the paper fully yet. But I'd like to ask if there is better way to define curves which wouldn't need to be "converted" first. E.g. do you know if I'd use NURBS to define all paths/curves, would it support faster equidistant arc length parametrization? Or some other way perhaps? Edit: By faster I mean using CPU or GPU.

Comment: Using NURBs won't help, the fundamental problem is the same.  The end of the paper shows a method of composing the re-parameterization curve with the original.  This produces a new curve with arc-length parameterization, but the order if the curve is higher, so it's slower to evaluate.

Answer (score 2):

I know this is an old question but I recently ran into this problem and created a `UIBezierPath` extention to solve for an `X` coordinate given a `Y` coordinate and vise versa. Written in swift.

https://github.com/rkotzy/RKBezierMath

```
extension UIBezierPath {

func solveBezerAtY(start: CGPoint, point1: CGPoint, point2: CGPoint, end: CGPoint, y: CGFloat) -> [CGPoint] {

    // bezier control points
    let C0 = start.y - y
    let C1 = point1.y - y
    let C2 = point2.y - y
    let C3 = end.y - y

    // The cubic polynomial coefficients such that Bez(t) = A*t^3 + B*t^2 + C*t + D
    let A = C3 - 3.0*C2 + 3.0*C1 - C0
    let B = 3.0*C2 - 6.0*C1 + 3.0*C0
    let C = 3.0*C1 - 3.0*C0
    let D = C0

    let roots = solveCubic(A, b: B, c: C, d: D)

    var result = [CGPoint]()

    for root in roots {
        if (root >= 0 && root <= 1) {
            result.append(bezierOutputAtT(start, point1: point1, point2: point2, end: end, t: root))
        }
    }

    return result
}

func solveBezerAtX(start: CGPoint, point1: CGPoint, point2: CGPoint, end: CGPoint, x: CGFloat) -> [CGPoint] {

    // bezier control points
    let C0 = start.x - x
    let C1 = point1.x - x
    let C2 = point2.x - x
    let C3 = end.x - x

    // The cubic polynomial coefficients such that Bez(t) = A*t^3 + B*t^2 + C*t + D
    let A = C3 - 3.0*C2 + 3.0*C1 - C0
    let B = 3.0*C2 - 6.0*C1 + 3.0*C0
    let C = 3.0*C1 - 3.0*C0
    let D = C0

    let roots = solveCubic(A, b: B, c: C, d: D)

    var result = [CGPoint]()

    for root in roots {
        if (root >= 0 && root <= 1) {
            result.append(bezierOutputAtT(start, point1: point1, point2: point2, end: end, t: root))
        }
    }

    return result

}

func solveCubic(a: CGFloat?, var b: CGFloat, var c: CGFloat, var d: CGFloat) -> [CGFloat] {

    if (a == nil) {
        return solveQuadratic(b, b: c, c: d)
    }

    b /= a!
    c /= a!
    d /= a!

    let p = (3 * c - b * b) / 3
    let q = (2 * b * b * b - 9 * b * c + 27 * d) / 27

    if (p == 0) {
        return [pow(-q, 1 / 3)]

    } else if (q == 0) {
        return [sqrt(-p), -sqrt(-p)]

    } else {

        let discriminant = pow(q / 2, 2) + pow(p / 3, 3)

        if (discriminant == 0) {
            return [pow(q / 2, 1 / 3) - b / 3]

        } else if (discriminant > 0) {
            let x = crt(-(q / 2) + sqrt(discriminant))
            let z = crt((q / 2) + sqrt(discriminant))
            return [x - z - b / 3]
        } else {

            let r = sqrt(pow(-(p/3), 3))
            let phi = acos(-(q / (2 * sqrt(pow(-(p / 3), 3)))))

            let s = 2 * pow(r, 1/3)

            return [
                s * cos(phi / 3) - b / 3,
                s * cos((phi + CGFloat(2) * CGFloat(M_PI)) / 3) - b / 3,
                s * cos((phi + CGFloat(4) * CGFloat(M_PI)) / 3) - b / 3
            ]

        }

    }
}

func solveQuadratic(a: CGFloat, b: CGFloat, c: CGFloat) -> [CGFloat] {

    let discriminant = b * b - 4 * a * c;

    if (discriminant < 0) {
        return []

    } else {
        return [
            (-b + sqrt(discriminant)) / (2 * a),
            (-b - sqrt(discriminant)) / (2 * a)
        ]
    }

}

private func crt(v: CGFloat) -> CGFloat {
    if (v<0) {
        return -pow(-v, 1/3)
    }
    return pow(v, 1/3)
}

private func bezierOutputAtT(start: CGPoint, point1: CGPoint, point2: CGPoint, end: CGPoint, t: CGFloat) -> CGPoint {

    // bezier control points
    let C0 = start
    let C1 = point1
    let C2 = point2
    let C3 = end

    // The cubic polynomial coefficients such that Bez(t) = A*t^3 + B*t^2 + C*t + D
    let A = CGPointMake(C3.x - 3.0*C2.x + 3.0*C1.x - C0.x, C3.y - 3.0*C2.y + 3.0*C1.y - C0.y)
    let B = CGPointMake(3.0*C2.x - 6.0*C1.x + 3.0*C0.x, 3.0*C2.y - 6.0*C1.y + 3.0*C0.y)
    let C = CGPointMake(3.0*C1.x - 3.0*C0.x, 3.0*C1.y - 3.0*C0.y)
    let D = C0

    return CGPointMake(((A.x*t+B.x)*t+C.x)*t+D.x, ((A.y*t+B.y)*t+C.y)*t+D.y)
}

// TODO: - future implementation
private func tangentAngleAtT(start: CGPoint, point1: CGPoint, point2: CGPoint, end: CGPoint, t: CGFloat) -> CGFloat {

    // bezier control points
    let C0 = start
    let C1 = point1
    let C2 = point2
    let C3 = end

    // The cubic polynomial coefficients such that Bez(t) = A*t^3 + B*t^2 + C*t + D
    let A = CGPointMake(C3.x - 3.0*C2.x + 3.0*C1.x - C0.x, C3.y - 3.0*C2.y + 3.0*C1.y - C0.y)
    let B = CGPointMake(3.0*C2.x - 6.0*C1.x + 3.0*C0.x, 3.0*C2.y - 6.0*C1.y + 3.0*C0.y)
    let C = CGPointMake(3.0*C1.x - 3.0*C0.x, 3.0*C1.y - 3.0*C0.y)

    return atan2(3.0*A.y*t*t + 2.0*B.y*t + C.y, 3.0*A.x*t*t + 2.0*B.x*t + C.x)
}

}
```