# Function for returning a list of points on a Bezier curve at equal arclength

Tags: math, bezier

Someone somewhere has had to solve this problem.  I can find many a great website explaining this problem and how to solve it.  While I'm sure they are well written and make sense to math whizzes, that isn't me.  And while I might understand in a vague sort of way, I do not understand how to turn that math into a function that I can use.

So I beg of you, if you have a function that can do this, in any language, (sure even fortran or heck 6502 assembler) - please help me out.

- prefer an analytical to iterative solution

EDIT: Meant to specify that its a cubic bezier I'm trying to work with.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you're asking for is the inverse of the arc length function. So, given a curve B, you want a function Linv(len) that returns a t between 0 and 1 such that the arc length of the curve between 0 and t is len.

If you had this function your problem is really easy to solve. Let B(0) be the first point. To find the next point, you'd simply compute B(Linv(w)) where w is the "equal arclength" that you refer to. To get the next point, just evaluate B(Linv(2*w)) and so on, until Linv(n*w) becomes greater than 1.

I've had to deal with this problem recently. I've come up with, or come across a few solutions, none of which are satisfactory to me (but maybe they will be for you).

Now, this is a bit complicated, so let me just give you the link to the source code first:
http://icedtea.classpath.org/~dlila/webrevs/perfWebrev/webrev/raw_files/new/src/share/classes/sun/java2d/pisces/Dasher.java. What you want is in the LengthIterator class. You shouldn't have to look at any other parts of the file. There are a bunch of methods that are defined in another file. To get to them just cut out everything from /raw_files/ to the end of the URL. This is how you use it. Initialize the object on a curve. Then to get the parameter of a point with arc length L from the beginning of the curve just call next(L) (to get the actual point just evaluate your curve at this parameter, using deCasteljau's algorithm, or zneak's suggestion). Every subsequent call of next(x) moves you a distance of x along the curve compared to your last position. next returns a negative number when you run out of curve.

Explanation of code: so, I needed a t value such that B(0) to B(t) would have length LEN (where LEN is known). I simply flattened the curve. So, just subdivide the curve recursively until each curve is close enough to a line (you can test for this by comparing the length of the control polygon to the length of the line joining the end points). You can compute the length of this sub-curve as (controlPolyLength + endPointsSegmentLen)/2. Add all these lengths to an accumulator, and stop the recursion when the accumulator value is >= LEN. Now, call the last subcurve C and let [t0, t1] be its domain. You know that the t you want is t0 <= t < t1, and you know the length from B(0) to B(t0) - call this value L0t0. So, now you need to find a t such that C(0) to C(t) has length LEN-L0t0. This is exactly the problem we started with, but on a smaller scale. We could use recursion, but that would be horribly slow, so instead we just use the fact that C is a very flat curve. We pretend C is a line,  and compute the point at t using P=C(0)+((LEN-L0t0)/length(C))*(C(1)-C(0)). This point doesn't actually lie on the curve because it is on the line C(0)->C(1), but it's very close to the point we want. So, we just solve Bx(t)=Px and By(t)=Py. This is just finding cubic roots, which has a closed source solution, but I just used Newton's method. Now we have the t we want, and we can just compute C(t), which is the actual point.

I should mention that a few months ago I skimmed through a paper that had another solution to this that found an approximation to the natural parameterization of the curve. The author has posted a link to it here: [Equidistant points across Bezier curves](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10477/equidistant-points-across-bezier-curves)

Comment: Man terribly sorry for not commenting on this TWO years ago when you posted it, I don't do much on SO because I have no reputation (which get me no rep.. yeah, yeah) .. but excellent answer and great code example, now for me to fully grock the response....