# Python - equally distribute objects across a bezier curve

Tags: python, math, bezier

I've read everything I could find here on the subject, and yet I don't manage to translate a part of the code to simple python I'd understand.

I got this, based on [this very good explanation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14174252/how-to-find-out-y-coordinate-of-specific-point-in-bezier-curve-in-canvas) of de Casteljau's algorithm:

```
def divideCurve(p0, cp0, cp1, p1, t):
    # p0 and p1 are the start/end points of the bezier curve,
    # cp0 and cp1 are the control points
    # all points are tuples of their coordinates: p0 = (10, 15)

    Ax = ( (1 - t) * p0[0] ) + (t * cp0[0])
    Ay = ( (1 - t) * p0[1] ) + (t * cp0[1])
    Bx = ( (1 - t) * cp0[0] ) + (t * cp1[0])
    By = ( (1 - t) * cp0[1] ) + (t * cp1[1])
    Cx = ( (1 - t) * cp1[0] ) + (t * p1[0])
    Cy = ( (1 - t) * cp1[1] ) + (t * p1[1])

    Dx = ( (1 - t) * Ax ) + (t * Bx)
    Dy = ( (1 - t) * Ay ) + (t * By)
    Ex = ( (1 - t) * Bx ) + (t * Cx)
    Ey = ( (1 - t) * By ) + (t * Cy)

    Px = ( (1 - t) * Dx ) + (t * Ex)
    Py = ( (1 - t) * Dy ) + (t * Ey)

    print Px, Py

for T in range(0, 11, 1):
    t = T*0.1
    divideCurve(p0, cp0, cp1, p1, t)
```

but this distributes the points unequally along the curve.

I've think [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2143471/function-for-returning-a-list-of-points-on-a-bezier-curve-at-equal-arclength) is a possible solution, but I completely don't understand the code for the inverse of the arc length function or how to translate it into python.
I found another approach [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11980166/equally-distribute-objects-across-a-bezier-curve/11981089#11981089) which I think takes a different approach which again I don't understand enough to implement in python.

If anyone's willing to clarify this into simple python, that'd be great.

Answer (score 4):

To start: this is a problem that has no symbolic solution, i.e. you cannot take the "length-for-t" function (at *t* value ..., the length of the curve is X) for a bezier curve and invert it so that you get "t-for-length" (if I'm at length ...% of total length X, which *t* value am I at). So all the implementations that you will find for this are variations on the theme

1. determine full curve length,
2. determine reference lengths for various *t* values along the curve, and
3. for values that don't exactly match the reference values, find the two *t* values near it, and interpolate.

Some implementations will flatten the curve for this (turn the bezier curve into a sequence of straight lines), others will construct a distance-for-t Lookup Table (LUT). Some implementations will do linear interpolation between the known reference values (effectively emulating a flattened curve), others will use arc interpolation, approximating each segment between two known values as a section of a (circular) arc. For all of these implementations, the bottom line is that your mileage will vary depending on the choices made, but all of them approach the "real" result the smaller you make the distance between consecutive *t* values.

The simplest, and usually the fastest, is to construct a LUT with a "small enough" stepsize between consecutive *t* values, and then not even bother with interpolation, instead picking the *t* point nearest to your actual length. As long as the stepsize leads to 1px or below segment lengths, for display purposes you don't need anything better than that, since a higher resolution won't actually lead to 'better' points, they'll be on the same pixel even if you make your distance reference points more precise.

I have a description of this, with code, up on http://pomax.github.io/bezierinfo/#tracing, it's in Javascript, rather than python, but given the algorithm description it should be relatively straight forward to just write up the Python based on the code you already have.